# PHP Finfo mimetype odd characters

Tags: php, image

using php's finfo class to find out the mime type of jpegs, ends up with infos like this.

I tried different jpegs.
System Ubuntu 14.04. php 5.5 apache2

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
 echo $finfo->file($file);
```

Result:

> image\057jpeg

When i add the extension database it goes more wired.

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, "/usr/share/misc/magic");
echo $finfo->file($file);
```

Result:

> application\057octet\055stream

With

> magic.mgc

the message changes.

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, "/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc");
echo $finfo->file($file);
```

> Warning: finfo::finfo(): Failed to load magic database at '/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc'

So the Magic file is missing, or better it is corrupt, because it exists!? Or what can happend? Please help.

Comment: `aptitude reinstall libmagic1`, does that help?

Comment: @Wrikken. No doesn't help

Comment: Well \057 _is_ a /, are you _sure_ you're doing a plain `echo`? Not some other thing / processing in between? Json-encoding and so on?

Comment: No, there is nothing between. The finfo output goes through a switch case and by default throws an Exception with the output string.

Comment: Have anybody else an idea, please. I've searched a lot but there is not much to find about this bug.

Comment: Does it happen if you just `echo` it & exit, and NOT throw an Exception? What modules have you loaded in PHP?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes it does. But now i think, i have the problem found. When i comment out `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');`, it is gone. So i have to search for the problem there.

Comment: Ah, yes, running `locale-gen` for the locale you would be using if you didn't explicitly switch over to that other (correct) one has a chance of fixing it then. What is your default locale actually?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the uncomplete

> /etc/default/locale

There was only one row

> LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

I've tried

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

but it gave me some errors.

So i deleted the contents of

> /etc/default/locale

and started the gui language setup

like here 
[askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them)
"answere from David A"

Thanks for helping